# Wordpress Update User's Password with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I have a webapp that uses Wordpress for it's authentication. I have an Account options page there. When opened, it contains a password update section. I POST this to my PHP script and run this code:

`wp_update_user(array('ID' => getUserIDWP(), 'user_pass' => $_POST['newpass']))`

It logs me out of my current Wordpress session, but when I try to log back in with the password I specified there, it says that I entered an incorrect password. I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this subject.

Note: the `getUserIDWP()` function is an alias for `$current_user->ID;` and the other related stuff.

Comment: wich version of wp do you have? I don't see the 'user_pass' entry in the usermeta table.

Comment: I don't actually remember what version I used - but it was the latest version when I asked that question. Probably an early 3.0 or 3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It worked for me to update `'user_pass'` using both `update_user_meta` and `wp_update_user`:

```
update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass', $newpassword);
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'user_pass' => $newpassword) ) ;
```

Comment: Does wp_set_password work? And do you need to hash the new password first?

Answer (score 13):

Try below code, it won't log you out after password change and it works with Ajax too. Also, no need to reset cookies/session after it.

```
$userdata = [
    'ID'        => 1,
    'user_pass' => 'new_password',
];

wp_update_user( $userdata ); // this will handle encryption and everything
```

Comment: _wp_set_password_ clears user cache so you will be logged out. If you want to log back in you can do: `wp_set_current_user ( wp_get_current_user()->ID ); wp_set_auth_cookie ( wp_get_current_user()->ID );`

Comment: @geraldo please refer updated answer, it will be a better solution if you don't want user to be logged out.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but...

I had a similar problem and it turns out there was an entry in the usermeta table called user_pass. I deleted that entry and I could log in again.

Maybe this will help somebody - I spent the last hour trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    global $current_user;
    $password = 'Abc123456';
    wp_set_password($password, $current_user->ID);
```